Largest number of vectors with negative inner product
I want to characterize the largest number of vectors on a unit sphere, such that any two of them have an inner product smaller than a negative constant. Formally, what is the largest number $n$, such that there exist
$$
x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in S^d,
$$
which satisfies that for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$,
$$
\langle x_i,x_j\rangle<-0.01?
$$
The answer for $d=2$ is 3, while the example being a equilateral triangle.
Specifically, I would like to know:

Is the largest n go to infinity when d goes to infinity?

If the answer to the first question is yes, is the maximal n grows linear in d?


Any thoughts are highly appreciated!

This one?
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208484/packing-obtuse-vectors-in-mathbbrd

If for some $C>0$ we assume $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\le-C$ for all $i\not=j$, we get
$$
0 \le \left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right|^2
= n + \sum_{i\not=j}\langle x_i,x_j\rangle
\le n-n(n-1)C
$$
which implies $(n-1)C\le 1 \implies n\le 1/C-1$.
So, for a fixed $C>0$, even as the dimension $d$ increases, the number of such vectors remains bounded by $n\le 1/C-1$.
We may also note that, like the case of the equilateral triangle providing $n=3$ for $d=2$, in higher dimensions there is a similar set of $n=d+1$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=-1/d$.
NB: The unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is usually denoted $S^{d-1}$, not $S^d$, but by your example I assume you ment vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Moreover, the maximum number of unit vectors with $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\le0$ for $i\not=j$ is $n=d+1$.
Both of these can be proven by induction. Without loss of generality, you can rotate the sphere so $x_n=[0,\ldots,0,1]$, $x_i=\left[\sqrt{1-r_i^2}x'_i\middle| r_i\right]$ where $x'_i$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ and $r_i$ is the last coordinate of $x_i$. Then, a solution with $n$ vectors in dimension $d$ will correspond to a solution with $n-1$ vectors in dimension $d-1$.

Your answer is perfect! Thank you so much.
